# Thunderbird--Lines on sides of email

Tags: windows-7

When you forward an email in Thunderbird 24, how do you remove the quote levels (meaning:
The lines on the sides of the email). I have searched the internet for an answer without luck.
In business when you forward an email with all those lines it looks very unprofessional.

With Eudora you click>message>forward. Then you put cursor in the body and
Click>edit>select all then click>edit>text>remove quote level.... until all quote levels
Are gone.

Thank You